# Could devtools::load_all() lazy-load the objects in data/?

Tags: r, devtools

I'm currently developing an R package that has several large objects stored under `data/` (several 50Mb files).

When I call `devtools::load_all('.')` from the console, it usually takes 10-20 seconds before the package is reloaded. Profiling that call reveals that most of the time is spent loading those data sets:

[image]

I would have thought that `load_all()` should lazy-load the datasets, but its documentation (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/devtools/versions/2.0.1/topics/load_all) states indeed that all objects under `data/` are loaded. But when I examine the environment of my package, I see only promises.

Is there a way to have `load_all()` lazy-load the objects in `data/`, so that the package loads faster?

Comment: that doesn't seem possible. you would have to do something custom, whether it's your own version of `load_all()` or moving / renaming the data files

Comment: It probably needs to read through the files to find out what objects need promises and to create the index.  The docs say you can speed up installation by creating the index yourself as a file named `datalist`; see Writing R Extensions for the format.  That might help `load_all()` as well.

Comment: @user2554330 nice callout, it will probably help users of the package. But it doesn't seem to speed up `load_all()`.

Comment: @lindelof:  in that case I'd recommend RStudio's "Install and restart" instead of `load_all()`.

Comment: @user2554330 that seems to take just as long. And I should perhaps have mentioned that my main motivation was to have unit tests run quickly; currently, hitting Ctrl-Shift-T begins with a call to `load_all()`.

Comment: Perhaps you could move the large datasets to some directory in `inst`, and just have code to read them when necessary.  That code probably can't live in `data`, since it seems `load_all` will execute it.